# Make package both Functional and OO

Tags: perl, package, cpan

I've seen CPAN Perl modules that can be used in a functional or OO way. I usually write OO and Functional packages depending on what I need, but I'm still not how write modules that can used both ways.

Could somebody give me a simple example of a package that can be used in functional and/or OO way? I'm obviously interested in the pieces that allows the package be used both ways.

Thank you

Comment: There are plenty of examples on CPAN. It's all just code. You can read it right there. Feel free to take a peak. :)

Comment: https://metacpan.org/source/LEEJO/CGI-4.40/lib/CGI.pm#L464

Comment: Ideally you don't. Make one package that is OO, and a second package that exports the OO module in a functional style, like `Object::Import` ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Import ).

Comment: @choroba blargh :D

Comment: The question you are asking is how to allow a procedural style user interface to co-exist in a module alongside an object oriented style interface.  Functional programming is a completely different paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

A core example is [File::Spec](https://perldoc.pl/File::Spec), which has a [File::Spec::Functions](https://perldoc.pl/File::Spec::Functions) wrapper. It's not so much object oriented but it does use the object oriented principle of inheritance, so its main API uses method calls, but it doesn't need to keep any state.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

print File::Spec->catfile('/', 'foo', 'bar');
print catfile '/', 'foo', 'bar';
```

Another example is [Sereal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sereal), whose encoder and decoder can be used both as objects or via exported functions which wrap them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sereal::Encoder 'encode_sereal';

my $data = {foo => 'bar'};

my $encoded = Sereal::Encoder->new->encode($data);
my $encoded = encode_sereal $data;
```

Sereal aside, it's usually good organizational practice to keep your object classes and your exporting modules separate. Especially don't try to have the same function be callable as a method or an exported function; the primary issue is that it's indistinguishable from the subroutine itself whether it was called as `$obj->function('foo')` or `function($obj, 'foo')`. As @choroba noted, [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) tries to do this and it's a mess.

Comment: As for "_indistinguishable from the subroutine itself_" -- correct, but no method expects its own object as an argument (it's already got it);  that example use is unreasonable (or, nearly impossible).  I agree that this is a cleaner and safer approach.  But you don't show an implementation (only use example from known modules) -- it isn't so clean and trouble free, which is why I think we have this question.

Comment: That example is _wrong_. I don't mean to assault your post but this matters. The equivalent of `$obj->func('foo')` is the call `func('foo')`, and not the one you show, `func($obj, 'foo')`. That one is just an error, wrong use of a function. Perhaps you mean to raise the question of how _an error_ plays out?  But those are open seas -- one can always break code with wrong input (normally trivial if you know the source).

Comment: @zdim You seem to have misinterpreted. From the perspective of the subroutine, `$obj->func('foo')` and `func($obj, 'foo')` result in the exact same contents of `@_` (though the first one may end up calling a different class due to method dispatch).

Comment: Hang on -- that sub call to `func()` is an outright error.  If the method `func` expects `'foo'` as its first argument then the function `func` in the same module must expect `'foo'` as its first argument.  Call `func($obj, 'foo')` is an error.  If you consider that first argument to possibly be an object, of some other class, then that can easily be correctly dispatched as a function call (see my answer).

Comment: @zdim I am talking about the implementation of Perl, not a specific subroutine's API.

Comment: I understand.  But in a class that we are talking about one _cannot_ have such a sub call (ie, it is a direct error) since the code for method `func` and sub `func` is the same.  Since it is legal code for the interpreter (and cannot be disambiguated), as you cay, I did accept raising it as a question of how an error is handled.

Comment: @zdim this statement was not supposed to be specific to how you might implement this, that was discussed on your answer. Let me put it this way. You write a subroutine that takes one optional string argument. `@_` contains a Path::Tiny object. Was it called as a method? `@_` contains your class name. Was it called as a method? There is no (sensible) way to programmatically distinguish if it was invoked as `Class->foo` or `foo('Class')` once the sub has been called and those are the contents of `@_`, so you can only guess, it might even be a good guess.

Comment: Again, (I think that) I get what you mean. (1) passing a `Path::Tiny` to a function results in the function call, correctly (2) My point: calling `foo('Class')` _is an error_.  It is equivalent to `Class->foo('Class')` which makes no sense.  (If it were in _another_ hierarchy then it is taken as a function call, correctly). And it does matter that it is in this particular API since it _must_ be an error in it. So: yes, it cannot be distinguished but it is an error. So it belongs to a different discussion (which is definitely legitimate and worthy), not as a generic failure of some approach.

Comment: @zdim How do you know 'Class' makes no sense as the first argument? Do I need to construct a whole hypothetical package where class names, or objects of that class, are common arguments? Regardless, it's an optional argument; calling the method with no argument on `Class` results in the exact same `@_` as `foo('Class')`. So if you say this must be an error, you can only disallow both, this is the limitation I am referring to.

Comment: Alright, slowly since there is an agreement mixed with other.  Let me start from the _method_ syntax: For `Class->func()` the correct call is `func()`; for `Class->func('Class')` the call is `func('Class')`. So once `func('Class')` is seen it gets dispatched to a (non-existent) `->func()`, incorrectly. This is a limitation, related to an unreasonable (while possible) use that I referred to in my first comment here.  It implies that a method takes an obj/class, not caring _which_ it is and allowing its own.

Comment: ... I think that the statement in the post I commented on doesn't clearly identify the point. The CGI you mention did quite well for being "_a mess_" (and I don't see that @choroba meant his link as criticism?)

Comment: Another point.  Imagine I write a method that takes an obj/class, and it doesn't care which it is (so, it's not meant to be `Path::Tiny` but it's _meant to be_ any).  Whoa, what does _that_ method do?  Well, perhaps something quite meaningful.  Now ... it is precisely _me_ who is going to write that function interface (or, the person who does will be well aware of what the method does).  So I _will not_ provide a function call for that involved method. Or, for it, I'll provide it as a separate name and rules.  My point: this is really a subtle, I'd say fringe, "limitation."

Answer (score 2):

My [WiringPi::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/WiringPi::API) distribution is written in such a way. Note that in this case here, there's no state saving required, so if keeping state is a necessity, this way of doing it won't work as-is.

You can use it functionally:

```
use WiringPi::API qw(:all)

setup_gpio();
...
```

Or use its Object Oriented interface:

```
use WiringPi::API;

my $api = WiringPi::API->new;
$api->setup_gpio();
...
```

For functional, I use `@EXPORT_OK`, so that the user's namespace isn't polluted unnecessarily:

```
our @EXPORT_OK;

@EXPORT_OK = (@wpi_c_functions, @wpi_perl_functions);
our %EXPORT_TAGS;

$EXPORT_TAGS{wiringPi} = [@wpi_c_functions];
$EXPORT_TAGS{perl} = [@wpi_perl_functions];
$EXPORT_TAGS{all} = [@wpi_c_functions, @wpi_perl_functions];
```

...and a few example functions/methods. Essentially, we check the number of parameters coming in, and if there's an extra one (which would be the class/object), we manually just `shift` it out:

```
sub serial_open {
    shift if @_ > 2;
    my ($dev_ptr, $baud) = @_;
    my $fd = serialOpen($dev_ptr, $baud);
    die "could not open serial device $dev_ptr\n" if $fd == -1;
    return $fd;
}
sub serial_close {
    shift if @_ > 1;
    my ($fd) = @_;
    serialClose($fd);
}
sub serial_flush {
    shift if @_ > 1;
    my ($fd) = @_;
    serialFlush($fd);
}
```

Typically I would do some parameter checking to ensure that we're shifting off the correct thing, but in testing, it was faster to allow the back end C/XS code worry about that for me.

Comment: @simbabque No. That's a very good point. Completely overlooked that. I'll update the answer with that statement.

Comment: Just replace `shift if @_ > 1;` with `my $self = @_ > 1 ? shift : get_global_object();`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, as always. That's really nice!

Comment: This approach prevents variable-length argument lists. I think I'd miss that. One could instead inspect the first argument (e.g. like CGI.pm does)

Comment: @ikegami Yep, it does. This is pretty much a pass-args-to-C-and-forget though, and to be honest, was one of my first real C library wrappers that I've done. Because it's been stable a couple years or so, I haven't revisited (I have however delved deep into perlxs, perlguts and perlcall since then, so this may be a good time to make this code a bit more dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

As stated, there are a number of modules that do this and some have been named. A good practice is to write a separate module for the functional interface, that `use`s the class and exports its (select) functions.

But it is quite possible to have both interfaces in one package, with same method/function names, if there is a specific need for that. See the section at the end for one *very* specific and rare use case that wouldn't be handled by the following basic example, and for how to resolve it.

Here is a basic package that has both interfaces

```
package Duplicious;  # having interfaces to two paradigms may be confusing

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);    
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(f1);

my $obj_cache;  # so repeated function calls don't run constructor

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_; 
    return bless { }, $class;
}

sub f1 {
    say "\targs in f1: ", join ', ', @_;  # see how we are called

    my $self = shift;
    # Functional interface
    # (first argument not object or class name in this or derived class)
    if ( not ( (blessed($self) and $self->isa(__PACKAGE__)) 
            or (not ref $self  and $self->isa(__PACKAGE__)) ) )
    { 
        return ($obj_cache || __PACKAGE__->new)->f1($self, @_);
    }   

    # Now method definition goes
    # ...
    return 23;
}

1;
```

The caller

```
use warnings;            # DEMO only --
use strict;              # Please don't mix uses in the same program
use feature 'say';

use Duplicious qw(f1);

my $obj = Duplicious->new;

say "Call as class method: ";
Duplicious->f1("called as class method");

say "Call as method:";
my $ret_meth = $obj->f1({}, "called as method");

say "\nCall as function:";
my $ret_func = f1({}, "called as function");
```

Output

```
Call as class method: 
    args in f1: Duplicious, called as class method
Call as method:
    args in f1: Duplicious=HASH(0x21b1b48), HASH(0x21a8738), called as method
Call as function:
    args in f1: HASH(0x21a8720), called as function
    args in f1: Duplicious=HASH(0x218ba68), HASH(0x21a8720), called as function
```

The function call dispatches to the method, thus two lines (note arguments).

I find it in principle awkward to use `Exporter` in a module that defines a class (but I am not aware of any actual problems with doing it); it results in a potentially confusing interface.  This on its own is a good reason to separate interfaces so that the functional one *has to* load a specific module.

There is also one detail that requires attention. The method call

```
($obj_cache || __PACKAGE__->new)->f1(...)
```

uses the cached `$obj_cache` (if this sub has been called already) to make the call. Thus the object's state is kept, that may or not have been manipulated in the previous calls to `f1`.

That is rather non-trivial in a call meant to be used in a non object-oriented context and should be carefully investigated.  If there are issues just drop that cacheing or expand it into a full `if` statement where the state can be reset as needed.

These two uses should absolutely *not* be mixed in the same program.

---

To test with a derived class I use the minimal

```
package NextDupl;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use parent 'Duplicious';

1;
```

and add to the main program above the following

```
# Test with a subclass (derived, inherited class)
my $inh = NextDupl->new;

say "\nCall as method of derived class";
$inh->f1("called as method of derived class");

# Retrieve with UNIVERSAL::can() from parent to use by subclass    
my $rc_orig = Duplicious->can('f1');

say "\nCall via coderef pulled from parent, by derived class";
NextDupl->$rc_orig("called via coderef of parent by derived class");
```

The additional output is

```
Call as method of derived class
    args in f1: NextDupl=HASH(0x11ac720), called as method of derived class

Call via coderef pulled from parent, by derived class
    args in f1: NextDupl, called via coderef of parent by derived clas
```

This incorporates a test using `UNIVERSAL::can`, as it came up in a comment.

---

There is one specific limitation (that I am aware of), raised and discussed in comments.

Imagine that we write a method that takes an object (or a class name) as its first argument, so to be invoked as `->func($obj)`; further – and this is what matters – this method allows *any* class as it works in a way that doesn't care what class it has. This would be very particular, but it is possible and it raises the following problem.

The function call corresponding to this method would be `func($obj)`, and when `$obj` happens to be in the hierarchy of this class that would result in the method call `->func()`, *incorrectly*.

There is no way to disambiguate this in the code that decides on whether 
it's called as a function or as a method, since all it does is it looks at the first argument. If it's an object/class in our own hierarchy it decides that this was a method call on that object (or a class method call), and in this particular case that is wrong.

There are two simple ways, and possibly another one, for the module's author to settle this

- Do not provide the functional interface for this highly specific method
- Give it a separate (clearly related) name
- The `if` condition that decides how we are called, by checking the first argument, is canned but still written for every method that has that interface. So in this method check one more argument: if the first one is object/class of this class *and* the next is (any) object/class then it's a method call. *This does not work if that second argument is optional.*

All this is completely reasonable.  In a class that exercises its defining trait, to have and use data ("attributes"), there will likely be methods that cannot be translated into function calls. This is because a single program should only use *one* interface, and with functions there is no state so methods that rely on it won't fly. (Use of a cached object for this is highly treacherous.)

So one will always have to decide carefully about the interface, and to pick and choose.

Thanks to [Grinnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5848200/grinnz) for comments.

---

Note that there is a completely different paradigm of "functional programming," and the title leaves that a little unclear. All this is about the functional interface in a procedural approach.

Comment: There are two problems with your "method detection" (which are shared by the unfortunate CGI.pm code): it doesn't respect inheritance, so it will break for subclasses; and it will assume you called it as a method if you pass an object as the first argument when calling it as a function, even if it's something like a Path::Tiny object which is commonly used as a string.

Comment: @Grinnz  Um, I thought the opposite (so excluded the call to `isa` --- see text) ... let me check ...

Comment: Not just that call to `isa`, but you also need to use `isa` rather than `eq` to check if it's a class name when it's not a ref, in order to allow the class method call on subclasses (e.g. `Subclass->f1`). It also needs to return an instance of $self or the class that $self is blessed into, rather than `__PACKAGE__`. All this work, and it still will also break when you do something perfectly valid like `my $sub = Class->can('f1'); OtherClass->$sub`

Comment: @Grinnz Well, no, when called with a wrong class's object it gets redirected to the normal method resolution, like in any straight-up class.  Perhaps I'm not see things straight?

Comment: @Grinnz The comment on the class-method call is good, of course; there is more work to do. It's meant as an illustration but maybe I pushed it too far.  Will review and add further commentary...

Comment: I think it's good to explore why it's a bad idea to do this :)

Comment: in response to "when called with a wrong class's object" - the point is that when you call the function and pass a Path::Tiny object as the first argument expecting it to be used as a string, you probably weren't planning on it thinking that you called the method *on the Path::Tiny object*.

Comment: @Grinnz  Ah, that's what escaped, right.  I'll review and perhaps take care of these (busy right now) ... it was meant only as an illustration.  I added a comment for now.

Comment: @Grinnz Completed edit with tests, I see no issues. Thanks for comments, it pushed me to complete the post.

Comment: My example `my $sub = Class->can('f1'); OtherClass->$sub` was meant to display usage with an unrelated class, and you may discover there is no way to both prevent ambiguity with passing unrelated objects as the first argument, and support this paradigm. Not to mention maybe it's a function where passing the package's class name as the first argument is valid usage! Your code is as close as you can get but it's still introducing logic that breaks expectations in certain cases, and there's no way to disambiguate it in a foolproof manner.

Comment: @Grinnz  But that would be a direct error, which can break just about anything.  Of course that there is no way to disambiguate -- no normal subroutine can handle that, and some will pop while some will carry on merrily.  How can one expect any sub to handle an arbitrary wrong input?  Besides, I can break established and good modules with `can`. That's a thorough test, and this behaves well _with correct input_.  I agree that it is not the best way, as I stated clearly -- but for reasons of style and design.

Comment: @Grinnz Or are you saying that you expect to be able to pull code for a method from one class and run it as a class method _by another class_?  That'd be horrible code, from which I wouldn't expect correct behavior in general. (I mean for any class, not this one.)

Comment: It's not a common case, but there is an expectation that it will behave as a method, at least. `$some_obj->Mojo::Base::tap(sub { ... })` is perfectly valid because the `tap` method doesn't care what it is invoked on.

Comment: My other point is more likely to come up: you might pass $input to the function, and at some point, that $input could be 'SomeClassThatInheritsYours'. I'm just trying to point out that you can handle 99% of cases but it is impossible to prevent bugs in this approach.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, hang on.  (1) What's that `tap` method? In general methods and subs very much care what their input is (2) So you are saying that if I call it as a function but pass an object/class_name of a derived  class, it gets dispatched as a class/method call, which wasn't intended? That's correct, but again it's a _kind of use_ with which I can break anything.  It's unreasonable. This is a (different) interface to a method code and one is fine to expect reasonable usage patterns.

Comment: @Grinnz Sure, it's not bullet-proof in any sense; I stated that prominently, right before the code.

Comment: @Grinnz No approach to any kind of acrobatics with OO is bullet-proof. Nearly any module can be made to misbehave with precisely crafted input.  The question is whether that input is (at least somewhat) reasonable to expect in intended use.

Comment: To put it even simpler: you don't have to jump through any of these hoops, and don't have any of these bugs by default, if you avoid sharing methods and functions entirely.

Comment: @Grinnz Heh, mixed good words and qualifications I object to :) -- (1) it's not much hoop jumping, one `if` statement to dispatch (2) What bugs? We talked above, I disagree that there are "bugs" -- there is a question of how _wrong use_ (ie, outright errors) is handled, and that is valid; but it's not a bug (3) I agree that it is better to separate, as I state clearly at multiple places in the post (and in these comments)

Comment: The hoop-jumping of getting the code right which took you a few iterations ("one if statement" that pretty much every implementation on CPAN gets wrong), avoiding the bugs such as your original code had, and the ones that remain which you disagree are bugs.

Comment: @Grinnz Correct, it took a few iterations and that's not desirable (if I were writing it as production code and not as an illustration in a typically hard-to-gauge SO post it wouldn't have).  As for what "remains," I agree that there is an ambiguity that affects _error handling_, and this is an issue. However, I do disagree that that is a bug -- or, half of CPAN has such bugs (perhaps lesser).  However, I will think more about it; maybe I _am_ not gauging it right.

Comment: @Grinnz  Above all, thank you for comments and this discussion.  Who knows whether I would have fixed and completed it otherwise.  I normally _do not_ resort to these kinds of things in my code. If it's a class it's a class.